# Ayuda con consultas PSQL-GRANT

Tags: mysql, pgadmin

estoy intentando dar permisos con grant, de lectura a todas las tablas y no consigo hacerlo.
Mi usuario es UserODBCToni y tengo que darle solo permiso de lectura(Select) a TODAS las tablas.
Gracias

Comment: con que gestor de bases de datos? cual consulta estas ejecutando? que fallo te da?

Comment: Es pgAdmin y openERP, consulta Select y no da ningun fallo, solo no se hacerlo

Comment: con gestor me refiero a mysql, postgresql, sql server, cual?

Comment: Si usas `pgAdmin` se supone entonces que estás usando `postgresql` como gestor de base de datos. Si es así, por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/227613/edit), cambiando la etiqueta `mysql` por la etiqueta `postgresql`. De paso, muestra qué instrucción SQL estás usando y qué error te está dando.

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO username; Pongo este comando que es lo que quiero que haga y me da error en que no detecta ALL